# Close Only One Chrome Tab on TaskBar

Tags: python

I have 2 chrome tabs like that:
[Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TGIu.png)

I want to close one of them.I will use python to close.How can I close?

Comment: You can kill one of the chrome instance, but which one is not guaranteed. Grep all running instance of chrome and kill using Id

Comment: Attached image is of windows 10 OS, so if you do such automation powerShell would be preferred

Comment: @ShivamSeth I tried to kill chrome by cmd: taskkill /pid chrome.exe but 2 both tabs are closed

Comment: I will use `os.system("cmd /c taskkill /pid chrome.exe")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using psutil module this can be achieved

Given code will kill first instance of process found. (If you want to kill all instance you can remove/comment return statement inside try block)

```
import psutil

def kill_process_by_name(processName):
    # Iterate over all running processes
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        # Get process detail as dictionary
        pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name', 'create_time'])
        # Check if process name contains the given name string.
        try:
            if processName.lower() in pinfo['name'].lower():
                print(pinfo)
                p = psutil.Process(pinfo['pid'])
                p.terminate()
                return
        except Exception as e:
            pass
            #ignore any exception


    return

kill_process_by_name( processName='chrome')
```

Comment: Please tell if this is helping or you need anything else